# Python Numpy mean of square calculation (is this the right way)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, mse

Not very good on python and numpy but working on a Mean Square Error for a machine learning code.

Want to do a python subroutine to return the mean square error based on the test_data and the following is the result.

The answer is great now (do not quote as x and y is already a matrix)

```
    for (x, y) in test_data:
        predictedMatrix = self.feedforward(x)
        actualMatrix    = y

    results = ((predictedMatrix - actualMatrix) ** 2).mean()

    return(results)
```

*** the original question is ***

My code does not look like python code and in fact the whole exercise does not look like other people numpy code on machine learning.  It works but it is no good.  Thanks for the advice as given.

```
import numpy as np
test_data  =      [(np.array([[ 0.        ], [ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]])),  # this is index not actually 1
                   (np.array([[ 0.        ], [ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                   (np.array([[ 1.        ], [ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                   (np.array([[ 1.        ], [ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]]))]

#import numpy as np

training_data = [ (np.array([[ 0.        ], [ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]])),
                  (np.array([[ 0.        ], [ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                  (np.array([[ 1.        ], [ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                  (np.array([[ 1.        ], [ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]]))]


#import numpy as np
validation_data = [(np.array([[ 0.        ],[ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]])), # this is index not actually 1
                   (np.array([[ 0.        ],[ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                   (np.array([[ 1.        ],[ 0.        ]]), np.array([[ 1.],[ 0.]])),
                   (np.array([[ 1.        ],[ 1.        ]]), np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]]))]

# We should do self.feedforward(x) but for here just

self_forward_x = np.array([[ 0.],[ 1.]])

test_results = [self_forward_x - y
                for (x, y) in test_data]

print "test_results : {0}".format(test_results)

#test_results : [array([[ 0.],[ 0.]]),
#               array([[-1.],[ 1.]]),
#               array([[-1.],[ 1.]]),
#               array([[ 0.],[ 0.]])]

# how to do sum of mean square error to check the progress of the epochs

# i.e. how to get mse which I think is
# (0**2 + 0**2)/2 + (-1**2 + 1**2)/2 + (-1**2 + 1**2)/2 + (0**2 + 0**2)/2 not / 4 as we have 4 cases ? should I divided by 4 ... confused.

sumarray = 0
i = 0

for arrays in test_results:
    for arrayi in arrays:
        #print "arrayi : {0}".format(arrayi)
        #print "sum(arrayi) : {0}".format(sum(arrayi))
        sumarray = sumarray + np.sum(arrayi**2)
        i = i + 1

return (sumarray / i)
# print "i, sumarray : {0}, {1}".format(i, sumarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Computing MSE in numpy is very straightforward:

```
mse = ((predictedMatrix - actualMatrix) ** 2).mean(axis=_axis)
```

_axis = 0 => Row wise computation to get a vector.

_axis = 1 => Column wise computation to get a vector.

_axis = None => Element wise computation to get a single number.

Comment: Many thanks. Still struggle with the loop but sorted.  Your answer is God sent. Thanks again.